# python beautifulSoup findAll

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, findall

I am having an issue getting all of the data from this site...
The section of the code I cannot get to produce all of the data is "pn"
I am hoping this code would product these numbers from the site.

58312-GA4
58312-RG4
58312-RR$

I have tried a number of things from switching the tags and classes and going back and fourth with find, findAll, and find_all and no matter what I try I am getting only one result.
Any help would be great - thanks
Here is the code:

```
theurl="http://www.colehersee.com/home/grid/cat/14/?"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

for pn in soup.find('table',{"class":"mod_products_grid_listing"}).find_all('span',{"class":"product_code"}):
    pn2 = pn.text
for main in soup.find_all('nav',{"id":"breadcrumb"}):
    main1 = main.text

    print(pn2)
    print (main1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the for loop for getting the 'pn' value quite separately from the for loop for the 'main' value. To be specific, by the time your code reaches the second for loop, the previous for loop has already executed in its entirety.

This results in the variable `pn2` getting assigned the last value that was returned by the for loop.

You might want to do something like

```
pn2 = []    
for pn in soup.find('table',{"class":"mod_products_grid_listing"}).find_all('span',{"class":"product_code"}):
    pn2.append(pn.text)
```

Comment: I am simply trying to increase the category by one up to 10.  The code is running but is blank.  If I run the code without trying to do this it works great.  When I add this to the code I am getting a response but it is all blank as if it doesn't recognize the page.  Here it is:

    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        theurl="http://www.colehersee.com/home/grid/cat/"+str(i)+"/?"

Comment: Sorry I sent that without explaining - I am only allowed to ask a question every 90 min so I thought maybe I could ask here...

Comment: You could try initializing ``i = 1`` instead of ``i = 0`` and making sure you increment the value of ``i`` by 1 inside the loop. And if you want the category upto 10, you'll have to use less-than-equal-to operator. i.e. ``while i <= 10:``